# Swift class add "@objc" for why

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Here's [a link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_402) to a Swift tutorial.

I read the protocol section,i know if protocol is marked with the @objc:

```
@objc protocol CounterDataSource {
    optional func incrementForCount(count: Int) -> Int
    optional var fixedIncrement: Int { get }
}
```

this mean this protocol in order to specify optional requirements and can be adopted only by classes

but tutorial didn't say why the class need to marked with the @objc too??

```
@objc class Counter {
    var count = 0
    var dataSource: CounterDataSource?
    func increment() {
      if let amount = dataSource?.incrementForCount?(count) {
        count += amount
      } else if let amount = dataSource?.fixedIncrement? {
        count += amount
      }
    }
}
```

if i remove @objc from class , compiler didn't show error message too

so what different between add @objc to class or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Deprecation**

It is no longer possible in latest Swift releases to use `@objc` w/o `NSObject` so this answer is deprecated.

**Original**

@objc is prefixed to classes to allow them to be used in ObjC. If you're dealing purely in Swift, it is unnecessary.

Also, if your class inherits from an ObjC class, the prefix is unnecessary.

Comment: But, only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared `@objc`. So when would `@objc` ever be useful in front of a class?

Comment: @AndrewPaulSimmons – you would be correct that it is not useful. In the past, it was possible to use `@objc` w/o `NSObject`, but this capability was removed in subsequent Swift versions. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For example `#selector` is owned by Obj-c,

In swift, we'll use  `#selector` in `.addTarget` or in `.target` of an object. There we should prefix `@objc` for targeting method.

Example:

```
@objc func dummy(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("xxx")
}
```

above method will be using in a UIButton's target like

```
dummyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. dummy(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

this is why we are using `@objc` as prefix in swift.